# c++ templates without "typename" or "class"

Tags: c++, templates, typename

i'm used to write templates like this:

```
template<typename T>
void someFunction(SomeClass<T> argument);
```

however - now I encountered templates in another thread written like this:

```
template<U>
void someFunction(SomeClass<U> argument);
```

as far as i know one can use "typename" and "class" interchangably (except for some details regarding nested types..). but what does it mean if i don't put a keyword in the brackets at all?

thanks!

the thread in question:
[Problems writing a copy constructor for a smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561115/problems-writing-a-copy-constructor-for-a-smart-pointer)

Comment: What is `U`? It is a typedef of `int` etc?

Comment: i don't know - if it was, would it make sense then? i'd also not understand if "U" was replaced by "int"

Comment: In such a case it could be a non-type argument (instantiated for example as `someFunction<10>`). BTW, the question is not about a template function, it's a constructor.

Comment: Your code is obviously typed from memory as it has syntax errors (no function return type). Please **copy and paste** the **EXACT code** so we can give a definitive answer otherwise everybody is just guessing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That code is wrong (typo). There must be a `typename` or `class` in this situation.

- [The one with `class` compiles](http://www.ideone.com/NIBsb).
- [The one without fails with `error: ‘U’ has not been declared`.](http://www.ideone.com/DPg9G)

---

However, it does not mean that all template parameters must start with a `typename`/`class`. This is because besides types, a template parameter can also be integral constants, so the following code works:

```
// template <int n>, but n is not used, so we can ignore the name.
template <int>
void foo(std::vector<int>* x) {
}

int main () {
  foo<4>(0);
}
```

and so is the following:

```
typedef int U;

// template <U n>, but n is not used, so we can ignore the name.
template <U>
void foo(std::vector<U>* x) {
}

int main () {
  foo<4>(0);
}
```

This is why I asked if `U` is a typedef in the comment.

Comment: I see - thank you! but what exactly is the point of using template without typename?

Comment: @Mat: If that `n` is really used, we could perform compile-time calculation. On a less-advantage setting, we could use the integer for e.g. an array size `template<class T, int n> struct Foo { T foo[n]; ... };`

Comment: Newbie question: We don't need `template` in that code. There is no point, right? Is it just for explanation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I think it was just an error of the person asking that forgot to add the "typename" or "class". The answers just copy/pasted the code, and it is also bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure U is a macro. 
I don't think a mere typedef would work in place of U, since compilers have to see either of the two keywords 'class' or 'typename' in the brackets in order for templates to compile.

Whoever put 'U' in there was a little too clever for their own good. Thus your confusion.

Welcome to the world of maintaining other peoples dirty code.

Comment: How would this theory explain how the second use of U works? :)

Answer (score 0):

If U is a type than this is a [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think so. If you substitute a parameter in the template, it should read `template <>`, and then the actual type used is in the signature of the method/function.